# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException

Tags: java

I have the following error when I try to run my program via Linux terminal :

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

But when I run it in my IntelliJ IDEA it doesn't throws this errors.

What causes the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you're entering a correct classpath (ie, one that allows the program to find all jars that it may need) on the command line?

Comment: It is a missing library (commons-cli) in your classpath.

Comment: Yes, I have it my .classpath file but it still produces the same error